# Getting parameter with correct format Angular

Tags: angularjs

I´m working with Angular and I pass a parameter from one controller to other like:

**Controller send:**

```
var input = { "ID": row[0].ID };
$scope.catalogo = JSON.stringify(input);
$state.go("root.detalleregistros", { catalogoid: $scope.catalogo
```

**State**

```
.state('root.detalleregistros', {
    url: "detalleRegistros.html/",
    templateUrl: "../SPA/administrador/catalogos/detalleRegistros.html",
    controller: "detalleRegistrosCtrl",
    params: {
        catalogoid: null
    },
    authenticate: true
})
```

**Recieve Controller**

```
$scope.catalogoid = $stateParams.catalogoid;
```

Problem is when the parameter is received, it results in: `{"ID":"1021"}` instead only `1021`, what should I need to do to receive only the number? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering why you are passing an object anyway and do all of this process. just pass the value
instead of

```
var input = { "ID": row[0].ID };
$scope.catalogo = JSON.stringify(input);
$state.go("root.detalleregistros", { catalogoid: $scope.catalogo});
```

use

```
$state.go("root.detalleregistros", { catalogoid: row[0].ID});
```

and save you effort and time doing something useful of course you can pass an object and get the property value of it but it would be unnecessary process. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Just access the value from Object,

```
$scope.catalogoid = parseInt($stateParams.catalogoid.ID);
```

Comment: I get `$stateParams.catalogoid is null`